# Jasper Report Character Encoding in PDF

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I am trying to use custom font in jasper report. `Myanmar3` is the standard font of Myanmar.
Everything is ok, but `ReportTitle` must be `Myanmar Font` with `Myanmar3`. 
`Google` also use `Myanmar3` for Myanmar locale.

When export the report as `html` file. It can display report title, well.But, Exported `PDF` file cannot display incorrectly.

In browser.

[image]

In PDF

[image]

```
public void report() throws Exception {
    List<SalesReport> saleReports = salesReportService.findSalesReport(new SalesReportCriteria());
    InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream("report-template/saleReportTemplate.jrxml");
    String outputFilePdf = "D:/temp/BasicReport.pdf";
    String outputFileHtml = "D:/temp/BasicReport.html";
    Map paramMap = new HashMap();
    paramMap.put("ReportTitle", "\u1005\u101B\u1004\u103A\u1038\u1021\u1004\u103A\u1038\u1019\u103B\u102C\u1038\u1011\u100A\u103A\u101E\u103D\u1004\u103A\u1038\u1001\u103C\u1004\u103A\u1038");
    paramMap.put("TableDataSource", new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(saleReports));
    JasperDesign jasperDesign = JRXmlLoader.load(inputStream);
    JasperReport jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(jasperDesign);
    JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, paramMap, new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(saleReports));
    JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfFile(jasperPrint, outputFilePdf);
    JasperExportManager.exportReportToHtmlFile(jasperPrint, outputFileHtml);
}
```

saleReportTemplate.jrxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" 
              xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
              xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" 
              name="TableReport" pageWidth="842" pageHeight="595" orientation="Landscape" whenNoDataType="AllSectionsNoDetail" columnWidth="802" 
              leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="30" bottomMargin="30" isFloatColumnFooter="true" whenResourceMissingType="Empty" uuid="a255c602-4ff1-4db8-ab72-65b5c3ff9bdd">

    <property name="ireport.zoom" value="1.0"/>
    <property name="ireport.x" value="0"/>
    <property name="ireport.y" value="0"/>
    <style name="Myanmar3" isDefault="true" fontName="Myanmar3" fontSize="10" isBold="false" isItalic="false" isUnderline="false" isStrikeThrough="false"/>
    <style name="Table">
        <box leftPadding="0">
            <pen lineWidth="1.0" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="TableHeader" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#808080"/>
    <style name="TableFooter" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#C0C0C0"/>
    <subDataset name="TableData" uuid="41cd3dac-2d22-41b9-9872-8fdb465d0f85">
        <field ... for table generation/>
    </subDataset>
    <parameter name="TableDataSource" class="net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRDataSource"/>
    <parameter name="ReportTitle" class="java.lang.String" isForPrompting="false"/>
    <title>
        <band height="153">
            <textField isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement uuid="b44cb7c1-f7d5-467c-8982-b95f65dcb849" x="106" y="0" width="573" height="59"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font size="22" isBold="true" isPdfEmbedded="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{ReportTitle}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <componentElement>
                -->other tag for table....
            </componentElement>
        </band>
    </title>
</jasperReport>
```

I already add `MYANMAR3.TTF` file and configure in `jasperreports-fonts-5.1.0.jar` for `myanmar3` font.

jasperreports_extension.properties

```
net.sf.jasperreports.extension.registry.factory.simple.font.families=net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fonts.SimpleFontExtensionsRegistryFactory
net.sf.jasperreports.extension.simple.font.families.dejavu=net/sf/jasperreports/fonts/fonts.xml
net.sf.jasperreports.extension.simple.font.families.myanmar3=net/sf/jasperreports/fonts/fonts.xml
```

font.xml

```
...other default config.

<fontFamily name="Myanmar3">
    <normal>net/sf/jasperreports/fonts/myanmar3/MYANMAR3.TTF</normal>
    <bold>net/sf/jasperreports/fonts/myanmar3/MYANMAR3.TTF</bold>
    <italic>net/sf/jasperreports/fonts/myanmar3/MYANMAR3.TTF</italic>
    <boldItalic>net/sf/jasperreports/fonts/myanmar3/MYANMAR3.TTF</boldItalic>
    <pdfEncoding>Identity-H</pdfEncoding>
    <pdfEmbedded>true</pdfEmbedded>
</fontFamily>
```

I have tested so many configuration, reference and example. But, there is no effect on `PDF` file.

**Let me know, if u have any suggestion and providing.**

Comment: Did you check the font in generated *pdf* file? Is it really *Myanmar3*?

Comment: @AlexK, Yes bro, I check PDF's properties. In Font' encoding is 'Myanmar3'.

Comment: @AlexK, Will I submit screen short?

Comment: Hmm... Did you try to set the style for *textField* (not to use the default style) element?

Comment: yes, I have tried it.

Comment: Ok, I'll try your report later. Does the parameter *ReportTitle* (in your *Java* code) contains the problematic text?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33492/discussion-between-alex-k-and-cycdemo)

Comment: There might be two issues, one is the text rendering (per Jongware) in JasperReports which is being produced by the iText library.  Second is the encoding of PDF.  Can you confirm the system encoding of your application, and possibly try forcing it to use UTF8?

Comment: I'm also facing the same problem. I used Myanmar3 and was able to embed the font to the PDF (Verified by checking the document properties of the PDF file). But the result is the same with CycDemo. Does anyone have a solution/workaround to this?

I also tried Zawgyi-One and it rendered nicely. Problem is it doesn't print properly (Just shows squares).

Answer (score 3):

This is a problem of [iText](http://itextpdf.com/) (version tested 5.5.4) and the `ttf` font, itext **doesn't support ligatures**, see comment below

Since jasper-reports is using itext as its library to render the pdf there is **nothing** you can do in jasper report to solve this problem.

Example code using **only iText** will render **same output** as jasper report

```
public class FontTest {

    /** The resulting PDF file. */
    public static final String RESULT = "pdf/fontTest.pdf";
    /** Test text. */
    public static final String TEST = "\u1005\u101B\u1004\u103A\u1038\u1021\u1004\u103A\u1038\u1019\u103B\u102C\u1038\u1011\u100A\u103A\u101E\u103D\u1004\u103A\u1038\u1001\u103C\u1004\u103A\u1038";

    public void createPdf(String filename) throws IOException, DocumentException {
        Document document = new Document();
        PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(filename));
        document.open();
        BaseFont bf = BaseFont.createFont(
            "lib/myanmar3.ttf", BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
        Font font = new Font(bf, 20);
        ColumnText column = new ColumnText(writer.getDirectContent());
        column.setSimpleColumn(36, 730, 569, 36);
        column.addElement(new Paragraph(TEST, font));
        column.go();
        document.close();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, DocumentException {
        new FontTest().createPdf(RESULT);
    }
}
```

I have posted a follow up [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34295596/font-myanmar3-not-rendering-correctly-in-itext) in [itext](/questions/tagged/itext) section to understand why itext can't render font correctly.

This is the comment of [@Bruno Lowagie](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1622493/bruno-lowagie) (Original developer of iText) is

> "The behavior you see is caused by the fact that iText **doesn't support
>   ligatures**. You need one of the next, unreleased versions of iText.
>   We'll release beta versions next year but only to customers."

Comment: Thanks for your explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Can you find out what text rendering engine Jasper-reports uses?

The font 'Myanmar3' relies *heavily* on OpenType Features to generate the correct sequences of characters. At a fairly high level, a text rendering engine relies on *low* level routines to handle correctly drawing of glyphs inside the font. That is, at the highest level you give the command to draw a certain text string. This string is decomposed into separate characters, which are then possibly re-ordered or replaced with glyphs according to the OTF rules inside the font. Only after that, a correct string of *glyphs* -- no longer 'characters' -- is sent back to be displayed.

From your description and screen shots it seems your browser *can* work with this font, but Jasper-reports cannot. That is visible in your PDF: your input string gets correctly decomposed (or possibly you are providing it in decomposed form) into separate base glyphs, but then the base glyphs do not get replaced back into composed glyphs by the text rendering engine. Hence the dotted circles under some of your characters; these are just placeholders, and were never meant to be drawn.

The precise point of failure cannot be determined. The font 'Myanmar3' contains all necessary information in `clig` and `liga` subtables, and these two are nothing special. However, the *script tag* is `mymr` -- maybe the text rendering engine is not aware of script specific features. Another possibility is that it cannot interpret the feature codes itself, as there seem to be lots of complicated chaining context strings here.

I don't suppose it's possible to manually change the text rendering engine for Jasper-reports? You may want to forward this *very* low level issue to its developers.