# Font (Myanmar3) not rendering correctly in iText

Tags: java, pdf, fonts, itext

In [jasper-reports](/questions/tagged/jasper-reports) section there is this [jasper-report-character-encoding-in-pdf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17653518/jasper-report-character-encoding-in-pdf/) question.

The problem can not be solved in jasper report since it seems to be an [itext](/questions/tagged/itext) problem (using iText v. 5.5.4)

**Example code:**

```
public class FontTest {

    /** The resulting PDF file. */
    public static final String RESULT = "pdf/fontTest.pdf";
    /** the text to render. */
    public static final String TEST = "\u1005\u101B\u1004\u103A\u1038\u1021\u1004\u103A\u1038\u1019\u103B\u102C\u1038\u1011\u100A\u103A\u101E\u103D\u1004\u103A\u1038\u1001\u103C\u1004\u103A\u1038";

    public void createPdf(String filename) throws IOException, DocumentException {
        Document document = new Document();
        PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(filename));
        document.open();
        BaseFont bf = BaseFont.createFont(
            "lib/mm3.ttf", BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
        Font font = new Font(bf, 20);
        ColumnText column = new ColumnText(writer.getDirectContent());
        column.setSimpleColumn(36, 730, 569, 36);
        column.addElement(new Paragraph(TEST, font));
        column.go();
        document.close();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, DocumentException {
        new FontTest().createPdf(RESULT);
    }
}
```

The font can be downloaded at [mm3.ttf](https://code.google.com/p/zawgyi/downloads/detail?name=mm3.ttf)

Will render incorrectly as:

[image: PDF RESULT]

it should render as (in browser using same `ttf`)

[image: Correct rendering]

Just out of curiosity what is happening? (seems like certain char, with dotted circles should move backwards but this is not happening).

Is this a problem with `.tff` or that iText does not support these kind of fonts?

Comment: The behavior you see is caused by the fact that iText doesn't support ligatures. You need one of the next, unreleased versions of iText. We'll release beta versions next year but only to customers.

Comment: @BrunoLowagie, 1000 thanks for your reply, look forward to new releases

Comment: Is it possible to address *glyphs* directly with this version of iText? Then all you need to know are the internal OpenType 'rules' for this font, and you'd be able to do the charcater translations in your code.

Comment: .. for example, the sequence `\u1004\u103A` ("င ်") translates into glyph indexes `109` `158`, and these are referenced in a Chaining Context lookup. A lookup (Lookup #54) changes glyph index `158` to glyph index `233` and leaves the other character unchanged. Glyph index `233` has no Unicode code point assigned to it so you indeed need to translate from and to glyph indexes, and be able to refer to these indexes when rendering the text string.

Comment: @Jongware thanks for your comments, I will look into if and how glyph can be accessed directly in itext (already seen this open question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33748186/accessing-opentype-glyph-variants-in-itext).

Comment: Petter, thanks for pointing that one out! At the time it was asked I noticed it as well – edited it for clarity, upvoted, and favourited it. But no results yet, so I'm going to draw some more attention to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Converting [Bruno Lowagie](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1622493/bruno-lowagie) (Original developer of [itext](/questions/tagged/itext)) comment into answer (community wiki)*

The behavior you see is caused by the fact that iText **doesn't support ligatures**.  (Current version on [github.com](http://github.com/itext/itextpdf/releases/5.5.8) **5.5.8**)

You need one of the next, unreleased versions of iText. We'll release beta versions next year (2016) but only to customers

Thanks to some bounty offered by [@Rad Lexus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2564301/rad-lexus) this other question about accessing directly openType glyph in iText has an answer [Accessing OpenType glyph variants in iText](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33748186/accessing-opentype-glyph-variants-in-itext)

Comment: I edited your answer because the official download page is on GitHub. Sourceforge is just a legacy backup.

Comment: Its not mine, its everybody's : )

Comment: We're at 5.5.9 now, but that is mostly a bugfix release. Not the new version that Bruno mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below codes,

```
string ZawgyiOnePath = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Fonts), "ZawgyiOne.ttf");
            BaseFont ZawgyiOneBaseFont = BaseFont.CreateFont(ZawgyiOnePath, BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED);

 iTextSharp.text.Font ZawgyiOneFont = new iTextSharp.text.Font(ZawgyiOneBaseFont, 9);
```